# In C# when using generics, and using the constraint where T : new() can the new() operator ever have a parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints, new-operator

I am trying to do something like this:

where DataTableLoader2 is a generic helper class

```
public static class DataTableLoader2 <T> where T : class, new (StringComparer)
```

Thanks for any help offered....

K

Comment: Have you tried this? Checked any documentation? What have you attempted?

Comment: Here's the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Comment: I did I read through MS docs & googled around, I could find no mention of anything other than a parameter less constructor. I have also tried multiple permutations & combinations to see if I could back my way into something the compiler would take. So far no luck...

Comment: `I could find no mention of anything other than a parameter less constructor` - well, that's because ONLY the PARAMETERLESS constructor is allowed within constraint definition.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @KeithVinson The answer to your question as asked is "no". But I suspect you have an X/Y problem here. You should ask a new question explaining what you're trying to achieve that makes you think you need this feature.

Comment: After a lot of searching, I finally found a suitable preceding duplicate. While the title isn't perfect, please read the linked question in full before saying it's not a dupe :) As a bonus, the answer accepted there provides a very handy workaround.

Comment: I think the intent of your question has been misunderstood. I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is just this `public static class DataTableLoader2 <T> where T : StringComparer` You can have a base class like `StringComparer` as a where constraint.

Answer (score 5):

No, it can't. The purpose of `new()` is simply to enforce that `T` must have a default, parameterless constructor. If you want to enforce a generic having some common initialization then you should do it through either a base class, or an interface.